# Program an animation to smoothly transition between all RGB values?

Tags: ios, animation, graphics

I'm trying to make a skin for a video game, where the skin just animates through all possible colors (like a rainbow glow).

I'm using iOS, which allows me to directly set RGB values by using a timer that fires very rapidly.

How should I go about doing this?

Should R, G, or B be changing at the same pace? Or should one value be faster?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using all the colors.  For the sake of clarity, have a look at this example. If you want any sort continuity in the color pattern, and not just a jumble of colors  you are going to want to pick a roughly linear plot, or at least a series of linear plots.  [image: 3D color plot] I would not recommend adjusting all three values at the same unless they are all adjusted identically, or relatively close. giving you a black to white fade, with all the colors in between.  If you really want to use all the colors, I would approach this piece-wise. Hold green constant, and increment red and blue equally, then hold red and blue constant and increment green.  It's really a matter of preference.  Look at objects like this to help you decide. but you will see the best results with linear, or nearly linear plots which start and end at the vertices.